# Mongoid write concern with w and j options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to set up both { "w": "majority", "j": true } for the write concern using Mongoid, so we can have writes success and good data as well as data backup from journals. While it doesn't look like I must choose between the two options: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/write-concern, the rails server started errorred out for the following validation error:

```
gems/optionable-0.2.0/lib/optionable/validator.rb:50:in `validate!': 
{"w"=>1, "j"=>false} is not acceptable for option :write. 
Valid values are: {:w=>any Integer}, {"w"=>any Integer}, 
{:w=>any String}, {"w"=>any String}, {:j=>true}, {"j"=>true}, 
{:j=>false}, {"j"=>false}, {:fsync=>true}, {"fsync"=>true}, 
{:fsync=>false}, {"fsync"=>false}. (Optionable::Invalid)
```

Comment: Using Mongoid 4.0.2 and MongoDB 2.6.9

Comment: It seems there is a bug in the validator. Try using a String (majority) instead of a Symbol (:majority), https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/4078